# Use Service as socket communication

Tags: android, sockets, android-fragments, data-management

**Concept**

So, I am making an Android application which communicates with a python server and acts as a controller for a music player.

**Architecture**

It consists of:

- `MainActivity`

  - `AlbumsFragment` (Displays GridView with albums)
  - `SongsFragment` (Displays ListView with songs)
  - `MusicControllerFragment` (Displays information about current song playing)
- `ConnectionService` (Has the socket object and sends, receives the messages from and to the server)

**Question**

The fragments need information like the albums and songs to show in a list. Now what is the best way to store the data and where. Should the AlbumsFragment use the Service to make a request to the server and retrieve the albums and store them. Or should I store the albums and songs in a `Application` class and use some sort of observer pattern to notify the fragment.

The fragments don't always have access to the service when it isn't bound. So I don't know it's the best way.

Any help is appreciated.